# Scrolling Main Below Header With Blur Backdrop Without Scrollbar Intersecting Header

Tags: html

Basically on my Website I want to have a header with a height of 50px. Below that I want to have the main content taking up the rest of the space. I want my header to have a blur backdrop filter and when the user scrolls down, the page should still be visible behind the header.

The issue is that if I only have the main content take up the area below the header, it will be cut of at the at the top and not appear behind the header. But if I put it at the top of the page with a 50px padding at the top, then the scrollbar will also fill the entire page, causing it to be on top of the header, instead of just taking up the area below the header.

Is there any way to get the main content to still be visible behind the header as it's scrolling out of view while having the scrollbar only take up the area where the main content is actually properly visible?

Here's my current code:

```css
header {
  background: #8888;
  backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 50px;
}
main {
  padding-top: 50px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
div {
  height: 200vh;
}
```

```html
<header>
  HEADER
</header>
<main>
  The Scrollbar And Header Are Intersecting :(<br>
  The Scrollbar And Header Are Intersecting :(<br>
  The Scrollbar And Header Are Intersecting :(<br>
  <div></div>
</main>
```

Comment: Please provide your existing code.